# Washing Machine in Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, icarus

So here is my
[Problem Statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leQHe.png) for the Washing Machine code.

I have written the module completely according to the given specifications but I am struck at the 100 clock cycles or 50 clock cycles .

I am not getting any idea of how do I make the code stop there and wait for 100 clock cycles or 50 clock cycles to execute having no effect on the output during clock cycle execution.

```
module Washing_Machine(clk,power,water_full,detergent_full,spin_dry,wash_ongoing,spindry_ongoing,state0,state1);
         input  clk,water_full,detergent_full,spin_dry;
         input  power;
         output reg wash_ongoing,spindry_ongoing;
  output reg state0;
  output reg state1;
            always @ (posedge clk)
            begin
              if(power == 1'b0)
                begin
                  wash_ongoing     = 1'b0;
                  spindry_ongoing  = 1'b0;
                  //idle state
                  state0         = 1'bx;
                  state1         = 1'bx;
                end
              else if(power == 1'b1)
                begin
                  case ({spin_dry,water_full,detergent_full})
                    3'b000 : begin
                                  //water state and waits for water full.
                                  wash_ongoing     = 1'b0;
                                  spindry_ongoing  = 1'b0;
                                  // water state
                                  state0         = 1'b0;
                                  state1         = 1'b0;
                             end
                    3'b010 : begin
                                  // water state and water full = 1 and 
                                  //goes to detergent state
                                  wash_ongoing     = 1'b0;
                                  spindry_ongoing  = 1'b0;
                                  //detergent state
                                  state0         = 1'b0;
                                  state1         = 1'b1;           
                             end
                    3'b011 : begin
                                  // detergent state and detergent full = 1 and 
                                  //goes to wash state and assigns
                                  wash_ongoing     = 1'b1;
                                  spindry_ongoing  = 1'b0;
                                  //wash state
                                  state0        = 1'b1;
                                  state1        = 1'b0;
                                  // now it waits for 100 clock cycles.....


                                  **I am struck here**
                                  
                                  
                                  //after
                                  wash_ongoing     = 1'b0;
                                  // spin dry state
                                  state0         = 1'b1;
                                  state1         = 1'b1;
                                  //assigns
                                  spindry_ongoing  = 1'b1;
                                  wash_ongoing     = 1'b0;
                                  // after 50 clock cycles.....




                                  // assigns
                                  spindry_ongoing  = 1'b0;
                                  // idle state
                                  state0         = 1'bx;
                                  state1         = 1'bx;                         
                             end
                    3'b100 , 3'b101 , 3'b110 , 3'b111 :
                    begin
                          // directly goes to spin dry state
                          // spin dry state
                          state0         = 1'b1;
                          state1         = 1'b1;
                          //assigns
                          spindry_ongoing  = 1'b1;
                          wash_ongoing     = 1'b0;
                          // after 50 clock cycles....



                          // assigns
                          spindry_ongoing  = 1'b0;
                          // idle state
                          state0         = 1'bx;
                          state1         = 1'bx; 
                    end                    
                  endcase
                end
            end
  endmodule
```

Comment: cross posted https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/565857/washing-machine-in-verilog

Answer (score -1):

You have to make a counter which increment or decrement 50 or 100 times. When the counter counts, stay in the same state. When the counter come to end, go to next state.

I think that you should start with [The Fundamentals of Efficient Synthesizable Finite State Machine Design using NC-Verilog and BuildGates](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsICU2002_FSMFundamentals.pdf)